# Rule of independent events.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is theorem which says that two events X and Y are independent if and only if P(X intersection Y)=P(X).P(Y). how to prove this theorem the other way round?

Comment: It's not theorem, it's the definition of independence. It makes little sense to prove definition the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, $P(X \cap Y) =P(X)P(Y)$ is often used as a *definition* of independence, in which case there is nothing to prove.

At best you could show it is a plausible definition by showing $P(X \cap Y) =P(X)P(Y)$ is equivalent to $P(X|Y) = P(X)$ and $P(Y|X)=P(Y)$ which is an intuitive statement of independence.